# (Look forward / Can't wait) + (to arrive / arrival)

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction

Regardless of the formality level, I was wondering which form is more natural (The verbal form or the noun form.)

> 1.a. I look forward **to you arriving**. 
> 1.b. I am looking forward **to you arriving**. 
> 1.c. I can't wait for you **to arrive**.

or

> 2.a. I look forward **to your arrival**. 
> 2.b. I am looking forward **to your arrival**. 
> 2.c. I can't wait for **your arrival**.

To me they all mean the same thing, the in each set, the former two are definitely more formal and less excited. Just I have no idea whether they all sound natural semantically or not.

Is it only a stylistic matter or there is something more thay I have to take into consideration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

!a and 1b are grammatically valid, but less natural than 2a and 2b. 1c is more natural than 2c.

"Arrive/arrival" is a bit formal.

In a spoken context, I might say "I can't wait for you to get here!".